# python Postgresql CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS is error

Tags: python, postgresql

I tried to learn about `postgresql` using `python`. I want to create condition CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS, but I always get an error. The error is :

> File "learn_postgres.py", line 27, in InitDatabase
> cursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS python_db")
> psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "NOT"
> LINE 1: CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS python_db

Comment: What is the version of Postgres you're using? The 'if not exists' clause is supported since 9.1.

Comment: Oh yap, I use 9.6 version. So, what should i do if i want teh condition like that ?? @9000

Comment: @9000 Are you sure that it is valid syntax for [`create database` statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createdatabase.html)? I do not see any `if not exists` there...

Comment: try `CREATE DATABASE python_db` instead.

Comment: @HaleemurAli That's working, but i want create condition if database not exists, my code will create database as automatic.

Comment: @StefaniJohnsson: Nope! I initially misread it for `create table`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Postgres does not support the condition `IF NOT EXISTS` in the CREATE DATABASE clause, *however*, `IF EXISTS` is supported on `DROP DATABASE`

There are two options:

1. Drop & Recreate (**WARNING**: This will result in losing any information stored in the database, do this only if you don't care about the stored data)

   ```
    cursor.execute('DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS python_db')
    cursor.execute('CREATE DATABASE python_db')
    # rest of the script
   ```
2. Check the catalog first & branch the logic in python

   ```
    cursor.execute("SELECT 1 FROM pg_catalog.pg_database WHERE datname = 'python_db'")
    exists = cursor.fetchone()
    if not exists:
        cursor.execute('CREATE DATABASE python_db')
    # rest of the script
   ```

Answer (score 4):

You could query from [pg_catalog.pg_database](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-database.html) to check if the database is exist like this:

```
SELECT datname FROM pg_catalog.pg_database WHERE datname = 'python_db'
```

Then from here you can add the logic to create your db.

Answer (score 3):

```py
from psycopg2 import sql
from psycopg2.errors import DuplicateDatabase

...
conn.autocommit = True
cursor = conn.cursor()

try:
    cursor.execute(sql.SQL('CREATE DATABASE {}').format(sql.Identifier(DB_NAME)))
except DuplicateDatabase:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer29 shoot be:
2. check the catalog first & branch the logic in python

> ```
> SQL = "SELECT 1 FROM pg_catalog.pg_database WHERE datname = TEST'"
> ```

```
cursor.execute(SQL)
exists = cursor.fetchone()

if exists == 'None':
    SQL = 'create database TEST'
    cursor.execute(SQL)
```